# For an acute triangle, prove that the sum of the distances from circumcenter to sides is equal to the sum of circumradius and inradius

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

> Prove that, if $d_a$, $d_b$, $d_c$ are distances between the center of circumscribed circle and acute triangle sides ($a$, $b$, $c$ accordingly), then
> $$d_a+d_b+d_c=R+r$$

I didn't do much, because I can not quite think of anything useful except somehow using this equations

$$d_aa+d_bb+d_cc=(a+b+c)\cdot r= 2S=2\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}$$

$$R=\frac{abc}{4S}$$

Where $S$ is area, $r$ is inradius, $R$ is circumradius, and $p$ is perimeter divided by two.

Comment: Do you mean the inscribed circle (tangent to the sides) or the circumscribed circle ( passes thorough the vertices)?  What are $r,R,pS$?

Comment: Circumscribed circle. r - is an inradius. R is the circumradius, S is area. p is the half of the perimeter

Comment: All these clarifications should be made by editing the question.

Comment: Already done it

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/carnot.shtml&ved=2ahUKEwilj7X4ovzxAhWMwzgGHR2vC94QFjAAegQICRAC&usg=AOvVaw0VTpCaTe-XQjUWkmQzVbTm&cshid=1627149168451

Comment: Sorry, I must have overlooked it.

Comment: Thank you, endgame yourgame, appreciate this. Gonna (re)write that proof tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

For the acute triangle $ABC$ with the circumcenter  $O$

\begin{align}
\angle CAB&=\alpha
,\quad
\angle ABC=\beta
,\quad
\angle BCA=\gamma
,\\
\angle COB&=2\alpha
,\quad
\angle AOC=2\beta
,\quad
\angle BOA=2\gamma
.
\end{align}

Triangles $COB$, $AOC$ and $BOA$ are isosceles, hence

\begin{align}
\angle COD&=\alpha
,\quad
\angle AOE=\beta
,\quad
\angle BOF=\gamma
\end{align}

and
\begin{align}
d_a=|OD|&=R\cos\alpha
,\\
d_b=|OE|&=R\cos\beta
,\\
d_c=|OF|&=R\cos\gamma
,\\
d_a+d_b+d_c&=
R(\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma)
.
\end{align}

And it is well-known that for any triangle

\begin{align} 
\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma&=\frac rR+1
,\\
\text{so, }\quad
d_a+d_b+d_c&=
R\cdot\left(\frac rR+1\right)
=r+R
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hints:

For equilateral triangle shown in figure a it is obvious:

$$(d_c=r)^2=(OB=R)^2-\big(\frac{AB=c}2\big)$$

$$\frac c2=R\cos 30^o$$

$\Rightarrow d_c=r=\sqrt{R^2-\frac 34 R^2}=\frac R2$

$\Rightarrow d_a+d_b+d_c=3d_c=3r=r+2r=R+r$

For other type I was thinking to use Euler,s nine point circle shown in figure b and following formula:

$\frac{d_a}{h_a} +\frac{d_b}{h_b}+\frac{d_c}{h_c}=1$

Should I find anything I will include in my answer.